# Using multiple while loops getting only 1 record

Tags: php

I am just starting to learn php, so bear with me...

I am trying to get a list of employees from a list of supervisors.
I am only getting the last supervisor ..

I am guessing that it is because I have the code in the wrong places..

Here is the code I have so far..

```
//Get List of Supervisors
$result_supervisors = mysql_query("SELECT emp_no as semp_no, full_name as sfull_name,employee_email as s_email FROM employees where supervisor = '1' ORDER BY emp_no");
// Initializes Supervisor Array 
$supervisors = array();
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result_supervisors, MYSQL_ASSOC))
{
 $supervisor = $row['semp_no'];
 $supervisor_name = $row['sfull_name'];
 $supervisor_email = $row['s_email'];
//add row to supervisors array
    $supervisors[] = array($supervisor, $supervisor_name, $supervisor_email);
}
//Get employee for the supervisor
$empquery = "SELECT emp_no, full_name, review_date,employee_email as e_email FROM employees where review_date < curdate() and employment_status !='2' and emp_supervisor = ". $supervisor ;
$empresult = mysql_query($empquery); 
while($emprow = mysql_fetch_array($empresult)) 
{
if ($emprow['cnt'] == '0')
{
    // no records for supervisor
}
else
{
    $emp_no =   $emprow['emp_no'];
    $full_name =    $emprow['full_name'];
    $e_email =  $emprow['e_email'];
    $review_date =  $emprow['review_date'];

//add row to employees array
    $employees[] = array($supervisor, $supervisor_name, $supervisor_email,$emp_no,$full_name,$e_email,$review_date);    
}
}
print_r($employees);
```

I am trying to put the results into an html table and email it to the supervisor for the end result..
But getting more than one supervisor is my biggest issue..

Is there an easy way to put the data into an html table.. in case someone knows why only one supervisor is being done...

Any help that can help a newbie?

KD

Comment: I don't see any immediate problems with your code. Are you sure there is more than one supervisor in your database?

Comment: [**Please, don't use `mysql_*` functions in new code**](http://bit.ly/phpmsql). They are no longer maintained [and are officially deprecated](http://j.mp/XqV7Lp). See the [**red box**](http://j.mp/Te9zIL)? Learn about [*prepared statements*](http://j.mp/T9hLWi) instead, and use [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli) - [this article](http://j.mp/QEx8IB) will help you decide which.

Comment: Use `count` function to check how many elements you actually have.

Comment: Yes there are seven records in the database as supervisors. Did a count...

Comment: Why are you querying a table named "employees" in order to build a list of supervisors?  Your first query only looks for "supervisor = 1", so why do you expect to get more than 1 supervisor?  You should be querying a table of supervisors and joining to their many employees.

Answer (score 0):

Change your first query:

```
$result_supervisors = mysql_query("SELECT emp_no as semp_no, full_name as sfull_name,employee_email as s_email FROM employees ORDER BY emp_no");
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this code :

```
//Get List of Supervisors
$result_supervisors = mysql_query("SELECT emp_no as semp_no, full_name as sfull_name,employee_email as s_email FROM employees where supervisor = '1' ORDER BY emp_no");
// Initializes Supervisor Array 
$supervisors = array();
$employees = array();
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result_supervisors, MYSQL_ASSOC))
{
    $supervisor = $row['semp_no'];
    $supervisor_name = $row['sfull_name'];
    $supervisor_email = $row['s_email'];
    //add row to supervisors array
    $supervisors[] = array($supervisor, $supervisor_name, $supervisor_email);

    //Get employee for the supervisor
    $empquery = "SELECT emp_no, full_name, review_date,employee_email as e_email FROM employees where review_date < curdate() and employment_status !='2' and emp_supervisor = ". $supervisor ;
    $empresult = mysql_query($empquery); 
    while($emprow = mysql_fetch_array($empresult)) 
    {
        if ($emprow['cnt'] == '0')
        {
            // no records for supervisor
        }
        else
        {
            $emp_no =   $emprow['emp_no'];
            $full_name =    $emprow['full_name'];
            $e_email =  $emprow['e_email'];
            $review_date =  $emprow['review_date'];

        //add row to employees array
            $employees[] = array($supervisor, $supervisor_name, $supervisor_email,$emp_no,$full_name,$e_email,$review_date);    
        }
    }
}
print_r($employees);
```